# I need a Hint on this Differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

Let $f$ and $g$ be two real functions, and we have 
$$ (f*g)(t)= \int_0^tf(s)g(t-s) \, ds $$
we have the following equation 
$$y'+ay=f(t) $$ where a is a constant and f is a function 
-/ prove that if $$ g(t)=e^{-at}, $$ then $$ y =f*g$$ is a solution to the equation verifing $$ y(0)=0.$$
by jsut replacing y in the equation as $$ \int_0^t f(s)g(t-s) \, ds $$ does that mean that $$ y' = f(s)g(t-s)$$
if so we will have 
$$ f(s)g(t-s) +a \int_0^t f(s)g(t-s)ds=f(t) $$
and by replacing g with $$ g(t)=e^{-at}, $$ 
then we have 
$$ f(s) e^{-a(t-s)}+a \int_0^t f(s) e^{-a(t-s)} =f(t) $$
How Do we solve this ?

Comment: What equation do you mean?

Comment: Perhaps it should be stated explicitly that you intend the domain to be $[0,\infty)$ and not $(-\infty,\infty)$. Only in the former case is this definition of convolution standard; in the latter case one uses $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ rather than $\int_0^t$.

Comment: yes right , I forgot the equation , I just posted it , I couldn't find a way  to begin this problem

Comment: What tools do you have? Integrating factor? Laplace transforms? ...

Comment: the simple way solution ,I'm new to differential equation just first and second order with simpler method of solving not yet familiar with other types like laplace transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need is the fundamental theorem of calculus to verify that $$y = \int_0^te^{-a(t-s)}f(s)\, ds \tag 1$$ is a particular solution of $$ y' + ay = f(t). \tag 2$$

here is way to see this. from $(1),$ we have $$ye^{at} = \int_0^te^{as}f(s) \, ds \tag 3 $$ differentiating $(3),$  with respect to $t,$  we find that 
$$ \frac{dy}{dt}e^{at} +aye^{at}  = e^{at}f(t) $$ cancelling $e^{at}$ gives you $(2).$

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to differentiate the correct answer and manipulate to find that it satisfies your differential equation, but I think it is better to start with the differential equation and aim at solving it. Try with this:

Write the differential equation as
$$
y'(s)+ay(s)=f(s).
$$
Then multiply with the integrating factor $e^{as}$, to get
$$
\frac{d}{ds}(e^{as}y(s))=e^{as}f(s).
$$ 
Then integrate (in $s$) from $0$ to $t$. I stop here, since I want you to do the work. Tell me if you need further hints.

Comment: ok thanx , i'll